# ProgressBar keeps loading (Android)

Tags: android

i want to do a Quiz App and the Questions should´ve a timer of 30 seconds, after that I want to do some stuff.
With my code, the Progressbar (circle) is just moving infinite. 
The ProgressBar should just go from 100 to 0 in 30secs.

Main:

```
ProgressBar progressBar;
int progressValue = 0;
Handler handler = new Handler();
ImageView buttonA1;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.frage1);
    getSupportActionBar().hide();

progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar2);
buttonA1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.iVAntwort1);

CountDownTimer myCounter;


    progressBar.setProgress(progressValue);
    myCounter = new CountDownTimer(30000,30000) {
       @Override
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
            Log.v("Log_tag", "Tick of Progress"+ progressValue+ millisUntilFinished);
            progressValue ++;
            progressBar.setProgress(progressValue);
       }

        @Override
        public void onFinish() {
        progressValue ++;
            progressBar.setProgress(progressValue);
       }



    };
myCounter.start();
        }
```

XML:

```
<ProgressBar
    style="?android:attr/progressBarStyle"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/progressBar2"
    android:indeterminate="false"
    android:minHeight="50dp"
    android:minWidth="200dp"
    android:max="1"
    android:progress="0"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
```

Comment: //Makes Invisible                                
 progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE); Remove the  progressValue ++;
            progressBar.setProgress(progressValue); in onFinish method

Answer (score 0):

It shows infinitely because you are not stopping it. Change the onFinish() function into

```
public void onFinish() {
    progressValue ++;
    progressBar.setProgress(progressValue);
    progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
}
```

Also I suggest you to lower the interval to 1000 mills or something. `myCounter = new CountDownTimer(30000,1000)`